# Pipeline issues with a new column not being found

Tags: r, pipeline, tidyr

I am trying to run the following code and keep getting "Error: object 'caloriesdif' not found".

Here is my code:

```
activity <-read.csv("dailyActivity_merged.csv")
head(activity)

calories <-read.csv("dailyCalories_merged.csv")
head(calories)

activity_and_calories <- merge(activity, calories, by=c("Id", "ActivityDay"))
head(activity_and_calories)

activity_and_calories %>%
  mutate(caloriesdif = Calories.x - Calories.y) %>%
  max(caloriesdif)
```

I can get it to bring up the caloriesdif column but not what the max value is.

I have tried reruning the code and changing the names of the variables but I cannot find the maximum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're piping the data frame `activity_and_calories` to `mutate()`, then you're piping the result of that to `max()`. `max()` is receiving a data frame object (the name of which can be represented by a period, "."). It doesn't know that `caloriesdif` is a column name - it thinks it's another variable in your environment, which doesn't exist, hence the error.

`max()` expects a vector of values, which you could supply using `pull()`.

```
activity_and_calories %>%
  mutate(caloriesdif = Calories.x - Calories.y) %>%
  pull(caloriesdif) %>%
  max()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to r so I'm still learning all the ins and outs.

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Please vote for/accept answers that do.